# Understanding the multiplication of scalars in an arbitrary field with real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

At the moment, I'm currently going through Serge Lang's *Linear Algebra*. In it, we are considering a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over an *arbitrary* field $K$. Assuming $V$ is equipped with a scalar product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>: V \times V \to K$, Lang says that $V$ is a **null space** if $\left<v,v\right> = 0$ for all $v \in V$. He then claims that this implies all vectors in $V$ are mutually orthogonal. The proof he gives is in fact, $$\left<v,w\right> = \frac{1}{2}[\left<v+w,v+w\right> - \left<w,w\right> - \left<v,v\right>]$$

I was tempted to say the RHS is simply $$\frac{1}{2}(0 + 0 + 0) = \frac{1}{2}(0) = 0$$
but then the last equality in that sequence got to me...

I could understand if for any positive integer $n$ and element $a$ in an arbitrary field $K$ we defined $na$ to be the sum of $a$ with itself $n$ times. However, if $a$ need not necessarily be an element of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, what would it mean to multiply $a$ by an arbitrary real number, say $\frac{1}{2}$? Can we even guarantee that this is always defined? Sorry if this question seems a bit naive.

Comment: I guess if it is a field then first of all, both $0$ and $1$ must exist, which they would be distinct if the field is non-trivial. Then $1+1$ must exist by definition of additive group. $\frac{1}{2}$ must also exist since it is the multiplicative inverse. Then $\frac{1}{2}$ multiples by $0$ is again defined since $($K\{0}, $\times)$ is a multiplicative group. I am not sure if this helps

Comment: @JustWandering Yes, that is very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a field $K$ contains a multiplicative identity that we denote by $1$. Then $1+1\in K$, and we call this element "$2$". Etc., so you get all positive integers (properly, you get an embedding $\mathbb N\to K$). The field $K$ has additive inverses, so you find $-1$ and $-n$ for all $n$. And it has multiplicative inverses, so there exists $k\in K$ with $2k=1$; we denote this element by $1/2$.